# Concept behind ERRORLEVEL in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I got this doubt please anyone explain it

```
@echo off
:: take any number between 1 to 1619 it is true
if ERRORLEVEL == 0 echo There was a problem with the command error returned  %errorlevel%
echo 0
if ERRORLEVEL == 1 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
echo 1
if ERRORLEVEL == 1619 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
echo 1619
:: greater than 1619 false
if ERRORLEVEL == 1620 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
echo 1620
if ERRORLEVEL == 658547 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
echo 658547
:: any negative number true
if ERRORLEVEL == -1620 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
echo -1620
if ERRORLEVEL == -63653 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
echo -63653
```

Why this ? Any concept behind this ?

Comment: it's either `if %errorlevel% == 5` (exactly "5") or `if errorlevel 5` ("5" or higher). Of course `if` has also "LSS", "GTR" and some more.  See `if /?`

Answer (score 0):

the command you are executing is the same as

```
if errorlevel 0 echo something
```

Check the `if /?` output.And because the `=` is a standard delimiter in batch here it is not taken into account. `if errorlevel` command checks if errorlevel is bigger or equal to the given number. If you want exact comparison use the build in dynamic variable `%errorlevel%`:

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo something
```